Prevent Data Theft: Can I ensure that design files can only be copied from a PC after proper authorization has been granted?
Our design team works on company-provided Windows PCs to create new designs. We have reason to believe that one of our designers is leaking our original designs to competitors. To prevent this, we need a solution that allows copying to an external USB device only after entering a password or command. While we understand that this may raise trust concerns, it is necessary to protect our intellectual property in the fashion accessories industry, where design theft is more common than you might think.
Our organization has implemented restrictions on internet access for PCs and attempted to disable USB devices through the registry editor. However, we still require a method to transfer files from the PC to the weaving loom. Changing registry entries is not feasible everytime.

Kaspersky Security Center or Active Directory Policy

Could you please elaborate on this?
